# Start of proof of Burnsides $p^aq^b$ Theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> **Theorem.** Every group of order $p^aq^b$ ($p,q$ primes $a,b \geq 0$) is soluble.
>
> **Proof.** Enough to prove that no non-abelian simple groups have order $p^aq^b$. [Then break $G$ into simple pieces $\implies$ must be $C_p \implies G$ soluble.]$\dots$

Why is it enough to prove that no non-abelian simple groups...?

Now I'm assuming there is a theorem that says that any finite group can be split into simple pieces (I have may forgotten this), but I cannot see why those pieces would be $C_p$? Nor do I see why this implies that $G$ is soluble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a composition series 
$$ 1 = G_0 \lhd G_1 \lhd \cdots \lhd G_n = G $$
such that each $L_i := G_{i+1}/G_i$ is simple. Being supgroups of $G$, the $G_i$ have order $p^{a_i}q^{b_i}$ for some $a_i$, $b_i$. Hence also the $L_i$ have orders $p^{c_i}q^{b_i}$. As $L_i$ is simple and there are no simple groups of order $p^aq^b$ for $ab \ne 0$ (that is what remains to prove!), we must have that the order of each $L_i$ is a prime power. As the only simple groups of prime power order are the cyclic groups, $L_i$ is cyclic for each $i$. Hence the above composition series for $G$ has abelian factors, that is, $G$ is soluble.

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that $G$ is nonabelian simple;

Start with let $G$ be a minimal counter example,

Then every subgroup and every quatient of $G$ must be solvable by the minimality of $G$. But we know that if $N$ and $G/N$ is solvable then $G$ is solvable. Thus, we must assume that $G$ is simple i.e $N=1$ or $N=G$.